# html sidebar data in not accessible

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, sidebar

I have a google sheet, I opened script editor and opened there two files, a script file and an html file. Here is what I have in my script file:

```
//to load html sidebar
function loadHome() {
  const htmlSidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("home");
  const htmlOutput = htmlSidebar.evaluate();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput);
}

//to create a custom menu
function createMenu(){
   const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   const menu = ui.createMenu("AC Paz");
   menu.addItem("Side Registration", "loadHome");
    menu.addItem("Order Framing", "loadFraming");
   menu.addToUi();
}

//to make sure custom menu is loaded on open
function onOpen(){
  createMenu();
}

//to access data passed on html input fields
function userClicked(userInfo){
 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Site Information");

  ws.appendRow([userInfo.firstName, userInfo.lastName, new Date()])
}
```

Here is what I have in my html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div >
            <input id="fn" type="text" >
            <label for="fn">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div >
            <input id="ln" type="text">
            <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
    </div>
    
    <button id="btn">Add</button>
       <script>
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
        
        function doStuff(){
        
        var userInfo = {}
        
        userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
        userInfo.lastName = document.getElementById("ln").value;
        google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
        document.getElementById("fn").value = "";
        document.getElementById("ln").value = "";
          }
        </script>
```

Here is my problem: when I type something in input fields and click the button, nothing is passed onto the spreadsheet, but, the entry gets cleared in the input fields.

Comment: I tried your code. It is working as expected. The only time that there is nothing passed onto the spreadsheet is when the sheet  "Site Information" is missing. Please check if sheet "Site Information" exist in your spreadsheet. Please share a sample document if this doesn't resolve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I copy-pasted the scripts onto new file under a different account and it worked. Strange. The sheet did exist, though, in the original spreadsheet. The original google sheet was in a business account, could that cause a problem?

Comment: I can't really tell, If you could write values to the cell using normal procedures (without sidebar inputs) there shouldn't be any issue with the account used. If you cannot write/read values to/from the spreadsheet, then there might be issues with the account. When you initially run/use apps script function it will open an authorization request to see,edit,create and delete your spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div >
            <input id="fn" type="text" >
            <label for="fn">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div >
            <input id="ln" type="text">
            <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
    </div>
    
    <button id="btn">Add</button>
       <script>
       window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
        
        function doStuff(){
        
        var userInfo = {}
        
        userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
        userInfo.lastName = document.getElementById("ln").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(){
          document.getElementById("fn").value = "";
          document.getElementById("ln").value = "";   
        })
        .userClicked(userInfo);
        
          }
          }
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

GS:

```
function userClicked(userInfo){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  ws.appendRow([userInfo.firstName, userInfo.lastName, new Date()])
}

function showMySideBar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'))
}
```